# Using the S7.Net library to read data wrong result

Tags: vb.net, automaton

I spent a couple of days to communicate with the PLC, now, I would like to call the read method, strangely, I get an incoherent value returned.

I would like to get the DWord DB172.DW1 value, the first value represents a quantity, the second one is either 0 or 1, my syntax is like this :

```
Dim result as Object = MyPLC.read(“DB172.DBW1″)
MsgBox(result.ToString & ” ” & result.GetType.ToString)
```

I obtain as displayed message :

> 12 System.UInt16

On DB172.DBW2, I obtain this one :

> 3073 System.UInt16

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What dows the MyPLC method do?

Comment: My bad, I failed to copy my code, I was actually calling the read method

Comment: In that case, it seems like your values are 12 and 3073, and variable types are UInt16, which makes sense because in Siemens PLC, 'Word' means 2 bytes. So do what Jim said...

Comment: And if the second one is either 0 or 1, why is it a 'Word' instead of a 'Bool'?

Comment: Many thanks DrDonnut but I could solve my problem. The DB 172 uses DWord, it's written on a document given to me by my contact

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `MyPLC` returns `System.UInt16`, which is two bytes. The hex value of 12 is C and of 3073 is C01.  It appears that `MyPLC(“DB172.DBW1″)` just returns the high order byte into a `System.UInt16` value and `MyPLC(“DB172.DBW2″)` returns both values.  You can try:

```
Dim u1 As System.UInt16 = MyPLC("DB172.DBW1")
Dim b1() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(u1)


Dim u2 As System.UInt16 = MyPLC("DB172.DBW2")
Dim b2() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(u2)
```

and examine the values in the arrays

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Jim for your reply, actually, it's a little more complex than I thought. 
Actually, to read the DWord number x, the first value is obtained by querying DB172.DBW(2x), the second value is obtained by querying DB172.DBW(2x+1)
So, for example, to read the DWord number 10, the 2 values are obtained like this :

```
Dim Value1 as byte = MyPLC.read(DB172.DBDW20")
Dim Value2 as byte = MyPLC.read(DB172.DBDW21")
```